# Maximize parameters which result in a distribution where every nth trial is heads

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

I have a question of type:

Suppose I toss a coin for m times, and I get a head every nth trial, from the previous one. So let's say every 3 trial. This would be: $\text{TTHTTHTTHTTH}\dots$. If the probability of a coin getting heads is $p$, how can I maximize $p$ to get the results mentioned above?

I am quite confused with how to do this, if I use a simple MLE to maximize a geometric distribution I would be maximizing it for one trial, but that means the next one won't be maximized?

So, maximing for $\text{TTH}$, means $\text{TTHTTH}$ and so on would never happen.

Other thing I can do is try to maximize a Binomial distribution, but then I wouldn't be ascertained to get the pattern I want, but something like: $\text{HTT}$.

My question is, is there a way to properly solve this (I am no expert in Probability theory, so I'm doing a naive mistake I'd appreciate any help!)? Is the question even solvable with MLE or am I asking too much?